# Why the list item is under the title tab?

Tags: ionic-framework

I am working on an Ionic App and I don't know why
 the list item is not visible why it is under the title tab?

```
Here is the link of code.
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jneypysb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `<ion-header-bar>` and `<ion-content>` with `has-header` class and I resolved.

Because you declared `<body ng-app="Hungroo">` it's necessary to define those module.

It follows a complete example:

```js
angular.module('Hungroo', ['ionic']);
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
  <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="Hungroo">
  <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-header bar-royal">
    <button class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
    <div class="h1 title">title</div>
    <button class="button button-icon icon ion-settings"></button>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content class="has-header">
    <div class="padding">
      <div class="list">
        <label class="item item-input item-select">
          <div class="input-label">
            First Things First!
          </div>
          <select>
            <option>one</option>
            <option>two</option>
            <option>three</option>
            <option>four</option>
          </select>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</body>

</html>
```